# Verilog assign statement result check

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, assign

new to Verilog (well, SystemVerilog really, but I found that for the very basic keywords like assign and initialize I am able to learn from Verilog resources as well). I am following example 2 on this link [chipverify example 2](https://www.chipverify.com/verilog/verilog-assign-statement). It's simple so I'll write it down. I feel as if they've made a mistake, but since I am a newbie it's hard to know if my feeling is correct or not.

```
module xyz (input [3:0] x, //let x='hC or x='b1100 for this example's purposes
            input       y, //y is a 1bit scalar y='h1 = 'b1
            output [4:0] z);
//case 8
assign z = {3{y}};

endmodule
```

For case 8, they are saying that z will result in z='b00111. I don't think it's correct! Following their case 3, where z only got bits [4:1] assigned,it stated that the reaming bit will be undriven and thus result in high impedance Z. Shouldn't the result of case 8 then be **z ='bZZ111** and not  **z='b00111**?

Let me know, thanks! =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From section 10.7 (Assignment extension and truncation) in IEEE Std 1800-2017 (the SystemVerilog standard),

> - When the right-hand side evaluates to fewer bits than the left-hand side, the right-hand side value is padded to the size of the 
>     left-hand side.

In your case, {3{y}} is an unsigned value, so it is 0-padded to 5 bits, that is 5'b00111, and then assigned to z.

Comment: So is case 2 
`//Case #2: 
assign z[3:1] = {x, y};` Result: **z='bZ001Z**
Is the reason that the RHS isn't padded with zeroes to be the same size as the LHS because the LHS specifies (3 bits) **z[3:1]**, while case #8 just says **z**, thus we are trying to fill all 5 bits and must pad RHS?